# Rendering a portion of a PUG template without refreshing page

Tags: html, node.js, express, pug

I have a pug template index.pug for my project. I have also made navbar.pug, footer.pug, sidenav.pug. These files are included in the index.pug. 
For server side I am using node.js, express.js and socket.io. Now I want to update only the navbar.pug file according to server response. But when I tried to do that I found some solution. But all of them refresh the full index page.
Is there any method that can help to update an specific portion of the webpage(in PUG) without refreshing the whole page?
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, pug is a server-side only HTML processor.  As such there is no way to do what you describe here - to get pug to process more means another round trip to the server to re-render the page.

Although technically you could do this with plain JavaScript, you should look into a client-side library like jquery, React, Angular, or Vue to do what you want.  A lot of us use pug in combination with those toolsets to build modern web apps, but with those frameworks pug becomes a quicker way to write HTML and is no longer a server-side pre-processor.