# how to fetch data while selecting there id without reload page

Tags: express

how to make live fetching data by express mysql and pug  ? 
i have a data in mysql and i want in view page when i select column_id then  fetch column_name and when i select second column_id then fetch the second column_name .. all this possible working automatically without reloading page ?

```
select(name='column')
 each x in columns
  option(value=2) column2
```

if id already selected then fetch there name here ...

```
h1 you selected id of this name : column2
```

Comment: Hi Sameer! I notice you've had quite a few recent questions, and unfortunately some of them have been closed. I wanted to mention that you might be able to increase the speed at which people can help you if you provide more details in your questions. If at all possible, it's great to provide a small working example of what you already have (people around here refer to that as a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). What you've provided is a beginning, but it's still tricky to understand exactly what's going on.

Comment: I answered this a few weeks ago here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57781967/rendering-a-portion-of-a-pug-template-without-refreshing-page/57791075#57791075

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rendering a portion of a PUG template without refreshing page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57781967/rendering-a-portion-of-a-pug-template-without-refreshing-page)

Comment: Yeah good call @Graham.

Comment: thanks guys, so is possible vuejs in pug template ?

Comment: The answer to the question you just asked in the comments is in the link I provided.  Please consider just deleting this entire Question as it already has an answer.